# check all function with outputting labels into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a group of check boxes and i want to use a check all function but only for the corresponding checkboxes for example if i click checkAll1 it will only highlight checkItem 1 but also will still allow me to check other check boxes.

you will see from the snippet below the code i currently have, i want to also be able to put the checkAll label when it comes out to the #check div to be in a p tag so i can style it.

hope this all makes sense

Many thanks

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    $("#checked").empty();
 $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
     $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + " ");
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll1"><label for="checkAll1">Check All</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1"> <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1"><label for="checkItem1">Item 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1"><label for="checkItem1">Item3</label>
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll2"> <label for="checkAll2">Check All</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2"><label for="checkItem2">Item 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2"><label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2"><label for="checkItem2">Item3</label>
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll3"><label for="checkAll3">Check All</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3"><label for="checkItem3">Item 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3"> <label for="checkItem3">Item 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3"><label for="checkItem3">Item3</label>
<p>You have selected:</p><div id="checked"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: id should be unique use name to group them

Comment: Assign the same class to the same row check boxes.. BTW check answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/32496460/2006386

Answer (score 1):

You can use value to call checkbox, Do something like this..

```js
var chk1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='1']");
var chk2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='2']");
var chk3 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='3']");
var chk4 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='4']");
var chk5 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='5']");
var chk6 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='6']");

chk1.on('change', function(){
  chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
});

chk3.on('change', function(){
  chk4.prop('checked',this.checked);
});

chk5.on('change', function(){
  chk6.prop('checked',this.checked);
});

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    $("#checked").empty();
 $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
     $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<p></p>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll1" value="1"><label for="checkAll1" >Check All</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2"> <label for="checkItem1" >Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2"><label for="checkItem1" >Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2"><label for="checkItem1" >Item3</label>

    <hr />
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll2" value="3"> <label for="checkAll2">Check All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="4"><label for="checkItem2">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="4"><label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="4"><label for="checkItem2">Item3</label>

    <hr />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll3" value="5"><label for="checkAll3">Check All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="6"><label for="checkItem3">Item 1</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="6"> <label for="checkItem3">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="6"><label for="checkItem3">Item3</label>
        
<p>You have selected:</p><div id="checked"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly :-) Thanks, is it possible to put the check all label in a <p> tag?

Comment: u mean , u need to add check all label in <p> tag like this ???  https://fiddle.jshell.net/ko0ao525/

Comment: ah no, i mean when the label is put into the #checked div

Comment: nope,lol ive added the html bit to what i want https://fiddle.jshell.net/ko0ao525/2/

Answer (score 0):

I tweak your code a little, and what you mean by `able to put the checkAll label when it comes out to the #check div` which i did't get it, try this below code :

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  $("#checked").empty();
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + " ");
  });
});

$(".checkAll").click(function() {
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
   $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  else
   $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- add class="checkAll" for checkAll checkbox only -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll1" class="checkAll">
  <label for="checkAll1">Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1">
  <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1">
  <label for="checkItem1">Item 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1">
  <label for="checkItem1">Item3</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <!-- add class="checkAll" for checkAll checkbox only -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll2" class="checkAll">
  <label for="checkAll2">Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2">
  <label for="checkItem2">Item 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2">
  <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2">
  <label for="checkItem2">Item3</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <!-- add class="checkAll" for checkAll checkbox only -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll3" class="checkAll">
  <label for="checkAll3">Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3">
  <label for="checkItem3">Item 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3">
  <label for="checkItem3">Item 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3">
  <label for="checkItem3">Item3</label>
</div>
<p>You have selected:</p>
<div id="checked"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

p/s : like other said, `id` must be unique for elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if you check them individually it works fine, so it puts the label in the div called #checked. if i click check all it will add all the   checked boxes or if i uncheck it removes them, does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a same class for the same row check boxes
Use the below jquery

```js
$("#checkAll1").change(function(){
$(".checkItem1").prop("checked", true);
});
$("#checkAll2").change(function(){
$(".checkItem2").prop("checked", true);
});
$("#checkAll3").change(function(){
$(".checkItem3").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll1"><label for="checkAll1">Check All</label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem1"> <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem1"><label for="checkItem1">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem1"><label for="checkItem1">Item3</label>

    <hr />
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll2"> <label for="checkAll2">Check All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem2"><label for="checkItem2">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem2"><label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem2"><label for="checkItem2">Item3</label>

    <hr />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll3"><label for="checkAll3">Check All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem3"><label for="checkItem3">Item 1</label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem3"> <label for="checkItem3">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem3"><label for="checkItem3">Item3</label>

<p>You have selected:</p><div id="checked"></div>
```

let me know if it is helpful